# 'iCloud Drive' missing from Finder (link broken?) in OS X El Cap

Tags: icloud

I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.6) on a Mid 2011 Mac Mini.

My 'link' to **iCloud Drive** in Finder is missing or broken. I know there is a physical location for the iCloud cache on the local SSD, but I cannot find it. If I could I *think* I could just add a Favorite to the sidebar. Much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found my answer here: http://usabilityetc.com/2015/07/access-icloud-drive-folder-in-terminal/

The location is:
`~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs`

Now I just need a way to add it back to the sidebar as a favorite...

Comment: I went to `~/Library/Mobile` then I could create an `iCloud Drive` alias and drag it to the sidebar.